# Unable to download large files from google drive using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I want to download large size files from google drive using python.
And I did this using below code

```
import pickle
import os.path
import requests
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import os
import pickle

class DriveAPI:
   global SCOPES
   SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']
   def __init__(self):
       self.creds = None
       if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
           with open('token.pickle','rb') as token:
               self.creds = pickle.load(token)
       if not self.creds or not self.creds.valid:
           if self.creds and self.creds.expired and self.creds.refresh_token:
               self.creds.refresh(Request())
           else:
               flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
               self.creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
           with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
               pickle.dump(self.creds,token)
       self.service = build('drive','v3',credentials=self.creds)
       results = self.service.files().list(pageSize=100,fields='files(id,name,createdTime)').execute()
       items = results.get('files',[])

   def download_file_from_google_drive(self,id, destination):
      def get_confirm_token(response):
          for key, value in response.cookies.items():
              if key.startswith('download_warning'):
                  return value
       return None

   def save_response_content(self,response, destination):
       CHUNK_SIZE = 32768
       with open(destination, "wb") as f:
           for chunk in response.iter_content(CHUNK_SIZE):
               if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                   f.write(chunk)

   URL = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download"

   session = requests.Session()

   response = session.get(URL, params = { 'id' : id }, stream = True)
   token = get_confirm_token(response)
   if token:
       params = { 'id' : id, 'confirm' : token }
       response = session.get(URL, params = params, stream = True)
   save_response_content(response, destination)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
   obj = DriveAPI()
   f_id = "File ID"
   file_name = "File Name"
   obj.service.permissions().create(body={"role":"reader", "type":"anyone"}, fileId=f_id).execute()
   obj.FileDownload(f_id,file_name)
```

By using above code I was able to download 2Gb size file for a certain period of time like 2 months. But now I'm unable to download large size files.
If I run this code the file downloads only 2.2kb file present.
But there is no issues that prints in terminal.

Comment: Is this happening to other files even if they are 1GB or 100kb?

Comment: no it is happening for above 2mb

Comment: The code you shared has anything else? I am getting a `get_confirm_token` is not defined and also `destination` is not defined.